# what language does S->aaSbb|SS|epslion make?

Tags: automata

I've been thinking about this for a day now,can someone help me ?

what language does S->aaSbb|SS|epslion make?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: I think that it can make a^n b^n | a^2n b^2n-2  a^2m-2 b^2m  | if m>=0 and n>=1

but I don't know what else it can make

Comment: First simplify it by replacing `aa` with `a` and `bb` with `b`. Then try some small examples (e.g. try to generate all strings of length $\le 8$ (there should be 23 such strings)) and try to find a pattern. Epsilon-elimination might also make the grammar clearer.

Comment: We're not particularly looking for posts that just state an exercise-style task and a request for us to solve it.  This is unlikely to be useful to others in the future.  What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Comment: (@Dmitry pray **don't** use the same symbol for more than one concept in any single presentation.)

Comment: @Jut your notation is ambiguous, as it is not clear if the $n$ is a global constant, or if it can change between different occurrences of $a^{2n}b^{2n}$.

Comment: @Jut aa aa aa bb bb aa aa bb bb bb is in the language but cannot be made by (a2nb2n)∗

Answer (score 0):

Let $L(G)$ as the language of grammar $G$ so

$$L=\{w\in\{aa,bb\}^* \mid n_a(w)=n_b(w)\text{ such that any prefix } u \text{ of } w:\ n_{a}(u)\ge n_{b}(u)\}.$$
(Note that $n_x$ count number of occurrence of $x$ in string $w$.)

Also you can prove that $L=L(G)$ by strong induction or try to show that $L(G)\subseteq L$ and visa verse.

Comment: And so, David lost the opportunity to solve the exercise themselves and learn something from this (also, there is a good chance that you participated in academic misconduct). At the very least you should describe how to arrive at the answer. (Also, your language is for grammar $S\to aSb|SS|\epsilon$)

Comment: @Dmitry Thank you. I think the question is not homework so I answer it. Also I edit my question.